# How can I receive value from an object to string or int or bool variable without casting?

Tags: c#

I have this function which is the GetPropertyValue , where I return an object then a property (type of string or integer or boolean) can receive the value of the object.

```
public string Name 
    {
        get { return this.GetPropertyValue(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name); }
        set { this.SetPropertyValue(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, value); }
    }

 public integer Age
    {
        get { return this.GetPropertyValue(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name); }
        set { this.SetPropertyValue(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, value); }
    }


 public object GetPropertyValue(string sPropertyName)
    {

        sPropertyName = sPropertyName.ToLower();

        if (mdPropertyBag.ContainsKey(sPropertyName.Replace("get_", "")))
        {
            return mdPropertyBag[sPropertyName.Replace("get_", "")];

        }
        else
        {

            return null;
        }
    }
```

The problem is I receive an error 'Cannot implicitly convert object to string' because function is returning object type where the caller type is either string, integer, bool etc.

`Get { return this.GetPropertyValue(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name); }`

Comment: What are you doing here? This is VB code and not C#. Are you trying to call this code from a C# application? Also where do you get the error (which line)?

Comment: Set a breakpoint in your code and work out exactly on what line it fails, it sounds like you are missing a ToString

Comment: I'm replicating the whole code to C# but I can't get it to work. I encountered the error here:  get { return this.GetPropertyValue(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name); }

Comment: Replace the VB with your C# code and tell us what line it fails on

Comment: Try sticking a `ToString()` at the end.

Comment: @MatthewWatson ToString() wont work. I also tried that.

Comment: `get { return (string)this.GetPropertyValue(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name); }`

Comment: @shigatsu: What do you mean by "won't work"? What happens when you use `ToString()`?

Comment: @EliArbel I'll take note this attribute when I migrate to VS 2012, but currently I'm using VS 2010

Comment: @MatthewWatson sorry for the previous comment, although it works in type string property but problem still occurs to type int or bool property when I use the function.

Comment: I found a workaround here. Instead of return a type object return function of type dynamic `public dynamic GetPropertyValue(string sPropertyName)` this way you don't have to cast each property to its designated type.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
public string Name
{
    get { return this.GetPropertyValue(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name).ToString(); }
    set { this.SetPropertyValue(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, value); }
}

public int Age
{
    get { return (int)this.GetPropertyValue(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name); }
    set { this.SetPropertyValue(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, value); }
}


public object GetPropertyValue(string sPropertyName)
{

    sPropertyName = sPropertyName.ToLower();

    if (mdPropertyBag.ContainsKey(sPropertyName.Replace("get_", "")))
    {
        return mdPropertyBag[sPropertyName.Replace("get_", "")];

    }
    else
    {

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: ToString would be ok to string type, how about the int type property?

Comment: see the second property, it converts object value into integer

Comment: @shigatsu `ToString()` works with all types.

Comment: Look closer at Age property getters after return keyword

Answer (score 2):

You have to explicitly cast an `object` to a `string` or an `int`, as `object` is the base class.

So use the following instead:

```
public string Name 
{
    get { return this.GetPropertyValue(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name).ToString(); }
    set { this.SetPropertyValue(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, value); }
}

public int Age
{
    get { return int.Parse(this.GetPropertyValue(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name).ToString()); }
    set { this.SetPropertyValue(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, value); }
}
```

Comment: I hope there is a way that I do not have to explicitly cast the object. Maybe a function will do.